# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

I am facing an issue while inserting some items into database in asp.net web service application.

Here is my code ..

```
 public void DoRequestLog(HttpRequest request)
        {
            string UserAgent = request.Headers["User-Agent"];
            string Date = "4/14/2011";//request.Headers["Date"];
            string HostIP = request.Headers["Host"];
            string URL = request.Headers["Referer"];
            string MethodName = request.HttpMethod;
            string VersionNo = "";
            string IMEINo = "";

        string dbString = Configuration.GetDBConnectionString();

        SqlConnection DardSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbString);

        DardSqlConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand log = DardSqlConnection.CreateCommand();

        log.CommandText = "insert into ConnectionLog values('"+UserAgent+"','"+Date+"','"+HostIP+"','"+URL+"','"+MethodName+"','"+VersionNo+"','"+IMEINo+"');";

        log.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Please Help 
Since I am new to .net environment.

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: Is this a DotNetNuke application?

Comment: Here , i am getting an error log.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void DoRequestLog(HttpRequest request)
 {
     // We don’t need to log anything if there is no HTTP request.
     if (request == null)
         return;

     string UserAgent = request.Headers["User-Agent"];
     string Date = "4/14/2011";//request.Headers["Date"]; 
     ...
```